# Dynamic parameters in postsharp

Tags: c#, postsharp, aop

I am trying to assign the property dynamically using post sharp. Such as in the below example I would like to have custom logging messages. But the problem is how could I set `xname` in the attribute part.In the first log I would like to have the logging message would have the persons name in the beginning but the second logging message would have the persons name at the end.

---

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
namespace ConsoleApplicationLogging
{
    internal static class Program
    {
        private static void Main()
        {
            Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(Console.Out));
            SayHelloInTurkish("Ayse");
            SayGoodByeSayHelloInEnglish("Elizabeth");
        }
        [Trace("xname Loglanıyor Gunaydın")]
        private static void SayHelloInTurkish(string personName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Hello, world.");
        }
        [Trace("Good Bye Logging for xname")]
        private static void SayGoodByeSayHelloInEnglish(string personName)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Good bye, world.");
        }
    } 
}
```

---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using PostSharp.Aspects; 

namespace ConsoleApplicationLogging
{
    [Serializable]
    public sealed class TraceAttribute : OnMethodBoundaryAspect 
    {
        private readonly string category;

        public TraceAttribute(string category)
        {
            this.category = category;
        }

        public string Category { get { return category; } }

        public override void OnEntry(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Method.DeclaringType != null)
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Entering {0}.{1}.",
                args.Method.DeclaringType.Name, args.Method.Name), this.category);
        }

        public override void OnExit(MethodExecutionArgs args)
        {
            if (args.Method.DeclaringType != null)
            Trace.WriteLine(string.Format("Leaving {0}.{1}.",
                args.Method.DeclaringType.Name, args.Method.Name), this.category);
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you need something like this (no sanity checking included):

```
this.category.Replace("xname", (string)args.Arguments[0])
```

If I did not understand correctly, feel free to comment below.